# Excel Searchable Database for Baseball Statistics

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have multiple years of statistics for my baseball team and would like to compile them into a searchable excel database. Here is a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmiIZ.jpg) to my setup for visual aids. Basically I have a work book for each year with each players per game stats listed on individual sheets (image 1) and a sheet which aggregates the individual players season totals into a team total(image 2). Having multiple years of stats, I would like to be able to search by player name and have something like image 3 appear showing the seasonal statistics of a player and tabulating their career total. I would also like to be able to search for team totals for a specific year and an individual's game stats from a certain year (image 1). For example if I were to type in Player A in one subject field and Career in another it'd pop up with something like image 3. I could also type in Player A and 2014 (or any year) and it'd pop up with image 1. Finally I would type in Team and 2014 and it'd pop up with image 2. I don't know if this is even possible with excel or if I need a more specialized or substantial program. I'm mostly asking for direction on how to get started. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You want to run a database from an excel data source - possible but not recommended. As a starter, try connecting from MS-Access to yor excel file, and running MS-Access reports and queries against it.

Comment: *I'm mostly asking for direction on how to get started.* Trial and error, pick up a book, scour internet forums & tutorials.  The answer to "Is it possible to do [x] in Excel/VBA?" is *almost always **yes**.*  But it is difficult to think of how anyone might "answer" this question in a satisfactory manner, without devolving into a never-ending string of follow-up questions.

Answer (score 0):

If all data is on one worksheet, perhaps try converting to table, add your required functions in the provided summary row, and use the provided filters.